# Boot from USB in HP laptop

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, linux-mint

I have HP Laptop Probook 4421s. I want to install Linux Mint 13 from USB drive. My usb is Toshiba 8 GB. I've tested in another laptop, it is working perfectly.

Bios Boot Priority is USB. When I'm start to boot my laptop , just nothing happen freeze or hang up my laptop. Anyone know about this issue?

Comment: ok i'm update my question :)

Comment: when you tested it on another laptop, did you mean you were able to boot from it? or just view the contents? And what or how did you create the usb boot? UNetbootin? other?

Comment: Change boot priority back to the hard drive (or whatever it was), save changes and exit bios then use F9 to get the one time boot menu, choose your usb drive from the list and hit enter.

Comment: @Logman i'm use this `sudo dd if=/path/to/file.dmg of=/dev/diskN bs=1m` 

i'm following step on this article 

http://renevanbelzen.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/creating-a-bootable-usb-stick-with-mac-os-x-in-10-easy-steps/

Comment: @Moab when i'm press f9 nothing happend just freze, so it can't be show list of drive for choice to boot...

but when i'm unplugged my usb still running again...

Comment: Try esc key to get a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed in my case

by create boot usb again using USB Startup Disk creator tool in ubuntu.

note: in my case i'm using linux mint 13 iso, but in picture is ubuntu it's depend...:)

[image]